# How to remove index values of multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, multidimensional-array

I have an array like

```
$my_array = Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => rock
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [1] => James
        )

     [2] => Array
        (
            [2] => John
        )
)
```

and I want array like this

```
array([0]=>rock [1]=>James [2]=> john);
```

I could get the array in this form. Please help me.

Comment: Why you are creating this type of array? Direct create as u want

Comment: Does the array really look like this? I'd expect both James and John to have an index of 0. If they are 0, then [array_column()](http://php.net/array_column) should give you what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Your array child contains the same key as the parent arrays, so you must use same keys for both!

```
$my_array = array(
      array( '0' => 'rock' ),
      array( '1' => 'James' ),
      array( '2' => 'John')
);
```

This will work:

```
$n_a = [];
foreach($my_array $k => $ma) {
     $n_a[$k] = $ma[$k]; //here is the problem
}
print_r($n_a);
```

`$n_a` contains final array.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that by a single line of code:

Using [`call_user_func_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php) with [`array_merge()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php),

```
$final_array = call_user_func_array('array_merge', $array);
```

Comment: great solved my problem thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution:

```
$newArray = [];
foreach ($data as $value) {
    $newArray[] = $value[0];
}
```

$newArray will hold the new array result

Answer (score 0):

Use foreach like this

```
$my_array = array
(
array
    (
        '0' => 'rock'
    )
,
array
    (
        '1' => 'James'
    )
,
 array
    (
        '2' => 'John'
    )
);
print_r($my_array);

$newArray = [];
foreach ($my_array as $key => $value) {
    $newArray[] = $value[$key];
}
print_r($newArray);
```